# Flatten and Export hierarchical clusters in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am working on R for the first time.
I want to flatten the hierarchical clusters i created in R (distance 0.0 - 1.0) at say 0.2, how can I flatten the clusters at this cut off point and then export the clusters in a file.

[image: Example Cluster]
Like here in this cluster you'll cut/flatten the cluster at the line marked. and the resulting cluster information should be exported to a file.
Here in this example 3 resultant clusters:

- A-(B-C)
- D-E
- F-G

Comment: What do you mean by "flatten the clusters"? How do you create clusters? can you add some code and data (reproducible example) please?

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `cutree`, as referenced from the **`hclust` documentation** in the "see also" section?

Comment: How to export the cut clusters?